# Render methods should be a pure function of props and state. But i just use function parameter

Tags: reactjs

Im create simple class and take this error. What wrong with using methot with parameters in class?

its pure value that i give to method.

```
class ClassCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: 0
    };
    this.changeCount = this.changeCount.bind(this);
  }

  changeCount (value) {
    this.setState({count: value})
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <h1>{this.state.count}</h1>
          <button onClick={this.changeCount(this.state.count + 1)}>Increment</button>
          <button onClick={this.changeCount(this.state.count - 1)}>Decrement</button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}

export default ClassCounter


Warning: Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state.
    at ClassCounter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:105:5)
    at div
    at App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute `onClick` expects a function to execute, instead, you were passing the output of the function which is undefined. Don't call the function inside `onClick`, instead pass it to be executed on the event.

Here is how you can fix it

```
<button onClick={(e) => this.changeCount(this.state.count + 1)}>
     Increment
</button>
<button onClick={(e) => this.changeCount(this.state.count - 1)}>
     Decrement
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your onClick functions to arrow functions:

```
<button onClick={() => this.changeCount(this.state.count + 1)}>Increment</button>

  <button onClick={()=> this.changeCount(this.state.count -1)}>Decrement</button>
```

when you execute your function in onClick,  it will try to change the  state, and it is a better approach to create a arrow function outside the render of your class and changing state in that function:

```
handleIncreament=()=>{
  this.changeCount(this.state.count + 1)
}
```

and use it:

```
<button onClick={handleIncreament}>Increment</button>
```

because react will create a new function in each render if you use arrow functions in render